# How do I update a collection in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to add a button action to a simple datatable but I am running into an issue with my collection variables.  I'm trying to copy the fields from the collection passed into the component to a new collection that stores details for my action button.

The problem I'm running into is that the last item in the source collection ends up populating each record in my new collection.

**testDatatable.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
            data={mydata}
            columns={columns}
            key-field={keyfield}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
    </lightning-datatable>     
</template>
```

**testDatatable.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track  } from 'lwc';

const COLUMNS = [
    {
        label: 'Name',
        fieldName: 'Name',
        type: 'text',
        sortable: 'true',
        initialWidth: 280
    },
    {
        label: 'Button',
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: { 
            label: 'Action',
            name: 'select',
            title: 'Click to do something',
            disabled: { fieldName: 'buttonDisabled' }
        },
        initialWidth: 90
    },
];

const MYDATA = [
    {
        Name: '',
        Id: '',
        buttonLabel: '',
        buttonDisabled: ''
    }
];
export default class TestDatatable extends LightningElement {

    @api tableData;
    @api columns = COLUMNS;
    @api keyfield = 'Id';
    @track mydata = MYDATA;
    @api copyData = [];

    connectedCallback() {
        // Add fields to datatable records
        console.log('Table',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tableData)));
        console.log('My',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mydata)));
        let myrecord = this.mydata[0];
        this.mydata = [];
        let filldata = this.tableData;
        // Make mydata have the same number of records as tableData
        filldata = filldata.map(repeat => {
                this.mydata.push(myrecord);
        });
        console.log('My-after',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mydata)));

        let i = 0;
        this.copyData = this.mydata;
        for(i=0; i<this.tableData.length; i++) {
            // let record = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tableData[i]));
            this.copyData[i].Plat_ID__c = this.tableData[i].Plat_ID__c;
            this.copyData[i].Name = this.tableData[i].Name;
            this.copyData[i].buttonLabel = 'Select'+i;
            this.copyData[i].buttonDisabled = false;
            console.log('Copy '+i,JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.copyData[i])));
            console.log('Table',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tableData[i])));
        }
        this.mydata = this.copyData;

        // ***** At this point, both collections are filled with each record being equal to the last record processed
        console.log('copyData',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.copyData)));
        console.log('mydata',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mydata)));

    }

    handleRowAction(event) {
        const action = event.detail.action;
        const row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail.row));
        const keyValue = row[this.keyfield];   
        console.log('Action,Key,Row',action.name,keyValue,row);
        // Change the label and disable the button here    
    }
}
```

**testDatatable.js-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="tableData" label="Accounts" type="@salesforce/schema/Account[]" role="inputOnly"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

**Test_Datatable.flow-meta.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <interviewLabel>Test {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}</interviewLabel>
    <label>Test Datatable</label>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>BuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>OriginBuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processType>Flow</processType>
    <recordLookups>
        <name>Get_Accounts</name>
        <label>Get Accounts</label>
        <locationX>358</locationX>
        <locationY>158</locationY>
        <assignNullValuesIfNoRecordsFound>false</assignNullValuesIfNoRecordsFound>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>Show_Table</targetReference>
        </connector>
        <object>Account</object>
        <outputReference>colAccounts</outputReference>
        <queriedFields>Id</queriedFields>
        <queriedFields>Name</queriedFields>
    </recordLookups>
    <screens>
        <name>Continue</name>
        <label>Continue</label>
        <locationX>223</locationX>
        <locationY>158</locationY>
        <allowBack>true</allowBack>
        <allowFinish>true</allowFinish>
        <allowPause>true</allowPause>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>Get_Accounts</targetReference>
        </connector>
        <showFooter>true</showFooter>
        <showHeader>true</showHeader>
    </screens>
    <screens>
        <name>Show_Table</name>
        <label>Show Table</label>
        <locationX>496</locationX>
        <locationY>158</locationY>
        <allowBack>true</allowBack>
        <allowFinish>true</allowFinish>
        <allowPause>true</allowPause>
        <fields>
            <name>Display_Datatable</name>
            <extensionName>c:testDatatable</extensionName>
            <fieldType>ComponentInstance</fieldType>
            <inputParameters>
                <name>tableData</name>
                <value>
                    <elementReference>colAccounts</elementReference>
                </value>
            </inputParameters>
            <isRequired>true</isRequired>
        </fields>
        <showFooter>true</showFooter>
        <showHeader>true</showHeader>
    </screens>
    <start>
        <locationX>50</locationX>
        <locationY>50</locationY>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>Continue</targetReference>
        </connector>
    </start>
    <status>Draft</status>
    <variables>
        <name>colAccounts</name>
        <dataType>SObject</dataType>
        <isCollection>true</isCollection>
        <isInput>false</isInput>
        <isOutput>false</isOutput>
        <objectType>Account</objectType>
    </variables>
    <variables>
        <name>colAppDefinitions</name>
        <dataType>SObject</dataType>
        <isCollection>true</isCollection>
        <isInput>false</isInput>
        <isOutput>false</isOutput>
        <objectType>AppDefinition</objectType>
    </variables>
    <variables>
        <name>colSelectedAppDefinitions</name>
        <dataType>SObject</dataType>
        <isCollection>true</isCollection>
        <isInput>false</isInput>
        <isOutput>false</isOutput>
        <objectType>AppDefinition</objectType>
    </variables>
</Flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you're not copying an object, but instead setting all of the indices to the same object. Here's a quick demonstration of that problem:

```
let a = {value:5};
let b = [a,a,a,a];
let c = b.reduce((a,v)=>a+v.value,0);
b[0].value=10;
let d = b.reduce((a,v)=>a+v.value,0);
console.log(c); // 20
console.log(d); // 40!
```

To fix this problem, you need to actually copy the object:

```
let a = {value:5};
let b = [{...a},{...a},{...a},{...a}];
let c = b.reduce((a,v)=>a+v.value,0);
b[0].value=10;
let d = b.reduce((a,v)=>a+v.value,0);
console.log(c); // 20
console.log(d); // 25
```

In your code:

```
this.mydata = filldata.map(value => ({...myrecord}));
```

This creates a new copy for each item, such that they won't be associated with each the initial object.

Also, I'm not entirely sure why you're making your code overly complicated, your "copy" routine could have been:

```
this.copyData = this.tableData.map(
  (c,i)=>({Plat_ID__c:c.Plat_ID__c,Name:c.Name,buttonLabel:'Select'+i, buttonDisabled: false})
);
```

Comment: Thanks - It got overly complicated as I kept trying different things to make it work.

Comment: You have been a great help to an old-timer with very little javascript experience trying to learn LWC.

Comment: @EricSmith You're welcome! Always glad to help when I can. I recommend checking out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) to learn more about JS, it's got a lot of quality-of-life improvements over most other languages.